# Want to find a way of doing the revert of 'onclick' in javaScript

Tags: javascript, css, event-handling, onclick

I want to find a way to make the page do something opposite to an onclick event.

So basically the below code shows how when a button (`li`) is clicked on it increases the padding, however i'm not sure of how to reset the clicked button when another button is clicked, something like an offClick which I know doesn't exist but I need a way to reset the padding back to how it originally was when another button (`li`) is clicked on within the same un-ordered List (`ul`), which is in this case `<ul id="menubar">`

Is there a simple way to do this?

p.s. please let me know if the question is not clear

```
<div class="container">
          <ul id="menubar" align="center">

          <li onmouseover="updateMenuItem(this)" onmouseout="revertMenuItem(this)" onclick="this.style.padding='20px'" >Page</li>


          </ul>
            </div>
```

Comment: That's not the opposite of an `onclick`. It's just an `onclick` that makes changes to the style of other elements.

Comment: I'd post an answer if you were using jQuery, but it's more work than I'm willing to do to try to write it in raw javascript.

Comment: @Barmar It actually is effectively because your clicking off the element, but thanks anyway! I'm using javaScript but if its easy to include jQuery then that's fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    function liClicked(clickedItem) {
        var list = document.getElementById('menubar');
        var listItems = list.getElementsByTagName('li');

        // reset the padding for all items
        for (var i = listItems.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            listItems[i].style.padding = '0px';
        }
        // set the padding for the item that was clicked
        clickedItem.style.padding = '20px';
    }
```

Comment: Hmm, not as verbose as I thought it would be. :)

Comment: yes but you are right in saying that jQuery is probably better for this sort of thing

Comment: I used this fucntion and set it up with the onclick as so: `onclick="liClicked(this)"` but it doesn't do anything when I click, does nothing at all.

Comment: Sorry I made a typo, GetElementById should start with a lowercase g

Comment: Ok, its increasing the padding when an `li` is clicked on but its not resetting all the rest back to their original state, so I click on all of them and they all increase in padding and stay like that